# Ошибка при запуске Unity

Tags: unity3d

я не могу запустить unity
[image: вот это появляется unity 2021.3 взял фото из интернета]

как мне запустить Unity?

Comment: Судя по тексту сообщения, Ваш процесс может быть заблокирован Защитником Windows или иной антивирусной программой. Проверьте, вдруг они и вправду блокируют запуск программы (ещё можно фаервол проверить — http://answers.unity.com/answers/1717322/view.html)

Comment: https://qna.habr.com/q/1005323 тут уже это делали , не помогло

Comment: отключи полностью дефендер и фаерволл и UAC и если установлен - внешний антивирус. И посмотри исправилась ли проблема. Если и это не поможет - проще будет винду переустановить